# Need help constructing a grammar (a^nb) with yacc, more specifically with conditions like n>=10

Tags: grammar, yacc, lex

Well, this is what I've done:

### lex

```
[a] returns A
[b] returns B
```

### yacc

```
%toke A B
%%
s: B | a B;
a: A | a A;
```

Now how do I accept only those strings where `n>=10`?

I thought of:

```
s : B | A A A A A A A A A a B
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why the `B |` at the start of `s`?. Without that, it seems to do what you want, so why do you need more "ideas"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YYFAIL or YYERROR for that:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int aCount=0;
%}
%token A
%token B
%%
s : aList B {
  if (aCount<10) {
    YYFAIL;
  }
}
anA: A {aCount++};
aList: anA | aList anA;
%%
```

Comment: +1, except you probably want to print your own more specific error message and call YYERROR instead of just calling YYFAIL (which will give a generic 'syntax error').